# Jar and find command

Tags: shell, jar, find

can someone help in creating a jar file that excludes directories using find command. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advnace

similar to below command I want to write in jar

```
tar --exclude="*/*/c" --exclude="*/*a" -cvf name *
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
jar cf test.jar `find . -not -path "*/*/c" -not -path "*/*a"`
```